# Text indexers (for python) with inbuilt support for doc, docx and pdf files

Tags: python, solr, full-text-search, whoosh, solr-cell

I am currently on the lookout for a text indexer for my python program. I shortlisted Solr, a Lucene project and Whoosh, which is native to python. I searched a lot of documentation on support for doc, docx and pdf files, and Solr kept pointing me to the Tika package, a version of which is integrated with Solr.

The results dont mention in certain terms if any package has **inbuilt support for the three formats**. Does Whoosh and Solr support them? Which other open-source indexer natively reads these formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Solr 1.4 or later you can have Word and PDF files uploaded and indexed on the fly; see: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler

> Solr's ExtractingRequestHandler uses Tika to allow users to upload binary files to Solr and have Solr extract text from it and then index it.

Comment: I've found extractOnly=true useful as I store my text in a sqldb, using Solr just for indexing/searching.